# Scrollbar in Flex/FlashBuilder application around set of content?

Tags: android, apache-flex, scrollbar, flash-builder, scroller

I'm having a bit of trouble programming a scrolling screen for an application I'm building in Flash Builder 4.7. I'd like to program so the map (images/ThirdFloor.png) doesn't scroll but the description does (images/FloorThreeGuide.png). Is there any possible way to do this? or can I only make the whole screen scroll? Thanks!

Code without scrollbar:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Level Three">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:HGroup>
        <!--this is a background image-->
        <s:Image source="images/background.png" height="100%" width="100%">
        </s:Image>
    </s:HGroup>

    <s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%" verticalAlign="top" horizontalAlign="left">
        <!--this tells the app to go back to the main page-->
        <s:Button chromeColor="0x9b063a" label="Home" color="0xffffff" click="navigator.popView()" styleName="back" width="100%" />
        <!--this is the third floor map-->
        <s:Image source="images/ThirdFloor.png"  width="100%" height="100%">
        </s:Image>

<!-- this is the section I want to scroll -->
        <s:Group>
        <!--this is a description for the floor exhibits-->
        <s:Image source="images/FloorThreeGuide.png" width="100%" height="100%">
        </s:Image>
        </s:Group>
    </s:VGroup>
</s:View>
```

---

This is what the code looks like when it's simulated to play on the device - click for image:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your Group in a Scroller:

```
<!-- this is the section I want to scroll -->
<s:Scroller>
    <s:Group>
        <!--this is a description for the floor exhibits-->
        <s:Image source="images/FloorThreeGuide.png" width="100%" height="100%">
        </s:Image>
    </s:Group>
<s:Scroller>
```

Comment: this broke the app/code. The guide image appeared larger than the screen itself (I get the image from the first heading, but nothing else and it definitely does not scroll)... [screenshot of what happened...](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8004CVfTo3gcWZwM04ycDNmTmc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: It looks like your "guide" image (really?  An image of text?) is huge, so when you place it inside the scroller, it looks way zoomed in.  Can you pinch-zoom it at all?  I'm not sure why it would cover your map image, though.  Did you set size constraints on the Scroller?

Comment: The image of text is all I was provided with. I cannot pinch zoom at all, and the scroller is set 100% height and 100% width.

Comment: How were you getting the whole screen to scroll?  Given that the Scroller isn't doing the trick, I'd be tempted to put a `verticalScrollPolicy=true` on your VGroup, but that would make the map scroll, too.  You could change the inner Group to a VGroup and set the scrollPolicy on it...tbh, at this point you're just looking at tweaking the layout code until it looks right.

Comment: As an aside re: image of text, I'd strongly recommend getting the individual pictures and the text from that image separately; then you can lay them out appropriately and even do things like scale the text based on the device DPI, click the image to get a full-screen version, etc. -- things that are ruled out by presenting a single image of the whole layout.

Comment: I'm trying to get just the image of text to scroll, the map is to remain stationary. unfortunately I cannot get individual pictures and text as the are scanned off a map (the map is avaliable to me, not the individual pictures nor the font used). This is going to take a bit more figuring out :/

Comment: verticalScrollPolicy=true generates the error "Cannot resolve attribute 'VerticalScroll' for component type spark.components.VGroup." 

I have tried to put the Scroller around the map and the description image, since this is a museum app, I have to use their official font and photos, which neither have become avaliable to me so I have been scanning them in off one of their older maps (so the image of text+thumbnail is going to have to stay, sorry - they're not supposed to zoom either, they're a thumbnail of the exhibit so visitors can glance and see exactly where they are...)